# Octave kernel for jupyter not working on windows 10

Tags: kernel, octave, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried to install the octave kernel for jupyter using pip (as suggested here https://github.com/calysto/octave_kernel).
But I cannot choose the Octave kernel when creating a new notebook.

It worked without problems on my Mac, so I guess it might be a Windows related issue.

Does someone have any ideas, how I could fix or investigate the problem?
Octave is installed.

Answer (score 4):

Setting environmental variable OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE to C:\\Octave\\Octave-4.2.1\\bin\\octave-cli.exe and restarting the PC solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

For me the version of Octave was important. It only worked when I installed Octave 5.2.0.