# Cannot open Octave within Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, windows-10

I've installed Octave on my Windows 10 PC, and used pip to add the octave kernel for Jupyter, but when I run `jupyter notebook` from the command line and go to Jupyter, I Octave doesn't appear under the New dropdown. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727607/octave-kernel-for-jupyter-not-working-on-windows-10#_=_) suggested adding the environment variable `OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE to C:\\Octave\\Octave-4.2.1\\bin\\octave-cli.exe`. The path to Jupyter is different on my machine - it seems to be `D:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.1.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli.exe` so that's what I've set my environment variable to that, and also put `D:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.1.0\mingw64\bin` on my path. Even after that, and rebooting, Octave still doesn't appear in Jupyter.

What do I try next?

Comment: You included the double \\ in your modified paths ?

Comment: Backslashes shouldn't need escaping in the Windows 10 environment variable editor.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you didn't install [octave kernel](https://pypi.org/project/octave-kernel/) I was into a similar situation initially though mine is not windows use

**pip3 install octave_kernel**  // I suppose you are using pip

If this didn't solve your answer please let me know the error when you run this

**jupyter console --kernel octave**